# How to properly preform ajax inside chrome extension content script on a secure site?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension and in the content-script file I have something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var currentHostname = cleanHostname(window.location.hostname);

$.ajax({
    url:    BASEURL + 'checkSite',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'get',
    data: {'hostname': currentHostname},
    success: function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
    }
});
});
```

This code works great on non-https site, as chrome allows non-https resources to be allowed on them. However, whenever I go to an https site I get this:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.google.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://localhost:8000/checkSite?hostname=google.com'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Which makes total sense. I understand this policy. But I think that an extension should get special treatment. How do I work around this? I've considered using background.js to do all the ajax and then do message passing, but I would strongly like to avoid that, but I will if needed.

Does anyone know?

Comment: You have to run the ajax request in the background of the chrome extension.  You can pass a message back to do this: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Comment: Really? only way? I implemented this, but it doesn't feel clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue by following @Brian's advice.

I just did all the ajax in background.js and used message passing to communicate with my content script.

Answer (score 1):

From [Here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) :

> **Requesting cross-origin permissions**
>
> permissions By adding hosts or host match
>   patterns (or both) to the permissions section of the manifest file,
>   the extension can request access to remote servers outside of its
>   origin.

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "http://www.google.com/"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Nope. That still causes the error when I run it on the page. The same HTTPS restriction.

Comment: Can you update your manifest  file? @Jaxkr

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nku1JgHh

Comment: try this out http://pastebin.com/pPBwTaDs

Comment: that's a little too broad of a permissions page. I just wrote it in a background script.